# REST wcf service doesn't work with data inside

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest

I have a web service on somee server. My database has 3 tables: Customer, Voucher, vPurchase. I was trying to make a code that allow customer to buy voucher from mobile device (android). What I did was send strings that content information of specific customer and the voucher he selected. That function returned true, mean it successfully inserted data into table of wcf service. But when I made a query to see if there was any data or not (by firefox), the service returns "The connection was reset" error. Since then, I couldn't access any data from those 3 tables anymore.
My solution was restoring the database (the state before doing the insert statement) then I could again access data in database (quite fun...)

I tried another test. I inserted one purchase into back up database on my computer and then restored to somee. The problem is same as before "The connection was reset"...

Update:
As I found some topics about Connection reset error. I tried to run the service on my local machine (the connection string still pointed to somee but the link was localhost...). Some of them worked!! I could retrieve the information of purchase, customer and voucher as well!! But funny, some of that returned "Server Error in '/' Application - The resource can not be found" even it still worked well on somee.

Any ideas where was I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I made it worked.

I referred to one of the topic on codeproject about passing email to wcf. I set the project to use IIS Express. After that, I uploaded it again to somee, and IT WORKED!!

It was such a nice experience!!